# mysqli query returns structure instead of data

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

When I do a query to my database this is the result:

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 3
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 3
    [type] => 0
)
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, 'melona');

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM votacion";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";

die();
```

Of course I don't want to obtain that, I want to get the rows contained in the table, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: A query returns a result set, which you can then fetch when, where and how you please (as an assoc array, as objects, as numerically indexed arrays...) that's how it works, and how it always has worked... also: don't `die`, but close the connections, and free the resources when you're done. Not _really_ needed here, but it's a good habit

Comment: Thanks, I applied your advice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to fetch the results out first, and to do that, you need to use either `->fetch_assoc()` or `->fetch_array()`:

```
// you need to loop it if you're expecting multiple rows
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['column_name'];
}
```

Ref:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Great, I used 

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
 $array[] = $row;

to get a good array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```